# How to change TextButton text color in Flutter

Tags: flutter, dart

How to change default TextButton text color in flutter here is my code

```
TextButton(onPressed: null, child: Text('Add Item'))
```

Comment: You can change it from the MaterialApp button theme and you will have it by default in all your buttons the theme you choose.

Answer (score 3):

Just add style property to Text constructor if you are not using a theme

```
TextButton(onPressed: null, child: Text('Add Item', 
style: TextStyle(color: Colors.purple)))
```

If You are using the default theme in the main.dart file then it will pick the accentColor or u can manually also provide

```
TextButton(onPressed: null, child: Text('Add Item', 
style: TextStyle(color: Theme.of(context).accentColor)))
```

Answer (score 0):

```
TextButton(
    style: TextButton.styleFrom(
        backgroundColor: Colors."anyColour", // if you want to change button colour
    ),
    
    child: Text('Your Text here',
        style: TextStyle(
        color: Colors."anyColour", // this is for your text colour
    ),
),
```

So your codes goes like this I believe

```
TextButton(onPressed: null, 
    child: Text('Add Item',
    style: TextStyle(
    color: Colors."anyColour",
    ),
),
```

Comment: Please provide additional details in your answer. As it's currently written, it's hard to understand your solution.